# How to masure maximum esc capacity

Tags: drone

I have a electronic speed controller(esc). I bought it from local store, so i don't know what is the capacity (maximum current capacity) how to find it? Plz guide me.

Comment: Google for its operating manual and hope that this aspect is covered in there. On a side issue - why would you buy a hat if you didn't know whether it would fit your head?

Comment: I need that for testing purposes. I want to see that what's in side this that's why i  purchase it. I want to know that how it sends signal to the motor.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule 1: No datasheet: no sale.** Don't buy stuff without datasheets. It generally signals that the vendor is not reputable.

Your only hope is to reverse engineer the ESC (note capitals for initialisation), figure out what chips or transistors are being used and then look up the datasheets for those.

Comment: Thank you now onwards i will takecare . Can you guide me how esc send signals to motor ? Based on our transmitter input. i mean how esc get to know that how much power motor will need ?

Comment: Don't accept the first answer that comes along. Wait a couple of days to give the whole world a chance to answer. You can un-accept for now. No, I'm not prepared to teach you how ESCs work. You should do your own research, study and if there is some point you don't understand then come back and ask a new specific question. "*Based on our transmitter input.*" What transmitter? Our? Input? It's not even a full sentence.

Comment: "No datasheet: no sale." - I've never seen a hobby grade ESC with a proper datasheet. Of course actual industrial BLDC controllers have datasheets, but good luck using them for RC aircraft.